# How to define an icon for my context menu item?

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How can I define an icon for a context menu item **without** declaring it in manifest.json?

For example I want to offer the possibility to change the icon in the options.

I thought I could use something like that, but nothing found in the Docs:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create( {'type': 'normal',
                             'title': 'CustomMenu',
                             'image': 'http://www.example.org/img.png'
                            }
                           );
```

Comment: When contextMenus was experimental, it let you set the icon.  It now pulls the icon from the manifest.json: See chrome's source: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/extensions/extension_menu_manager.cc?content-type=text%2Fplain

Comment: Do you know whether that function will be put into the "normal" API again - in the next versions?

Comment: No, I don't. It would be a cool feature, but I think they decided to use the extension's icon so devs couldn't masquerade as some other extension, and it helps users know which menus are default and which are extras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the current documentation: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html
You cannot update the icon.